# How To Turn A Query / Filter Formula Into An Array Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a data range that keeps track of individuals who request tasks to complete, including their names, their progress etc.
So in order to not give new tasks to those with uncompleted previous batches, I've set up the following formula to "alert" me.

`=iferror(query(filter($C$1:$E,$C:$C=$C3,D:D<30),"select Col2 LIMIT 1"))`

Is there, however, a way to make this into an array formula instead of populating individual cells? I've tried wrapping it in "array formula" but nothing happens. (Is this unarray-able?)

Link to sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wCAs9hkJeLmuUxwbxrosQlHwCw8DFPrigszz5cYYzyI/edit#gid=661764262

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with
=arrayformula(if(C3:C="","",iferror(VLOOKUP (C3:C, query(C3:D, "select C, Min(D) where D<30 group by C"), 2,false))))

Comment: I have a really weird/silly problem. When I copied your formula over to another sheet, it doesn't work. The data, the placement in the sheet, everything is identical, and so is the formula, but... it just doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup(C3:C30,query(C3:D,"select * where D<30 and D is not null"),2,0)))
```

the question is : do you need the minimum or the first qty ?

Comment: I'm okay if it returns any value under 30 as the main purpose is just to "alert."

Comment: I see it working now! Thank you so much for your help! Can I ask why it doesn't work when I arrayformula my original formula? Is it because of FILTER?

Comment: It is due to `LIMIT 1` that applies to all the data ... so you only fetch the first value of all the vlookup process.